# Rails object loses params value while creating it

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, jcrop

I have **Product** model with some params (price, category_id, image etc.).

When creating a new product in the form partial, category is being selected via `select_tag` and image gets uploaded via Carrierwave, image uploader. Bad things happens when I send user to crop the uploaded image in `crop.html.erb` file. There user crops image, clicks submit, which uses path as update (not very sure which HTTP protocol), and gets redirected into product edit page, since product somehow lost `category_id` parameter. Form shows error to select a category (all other params from input_fields does not get lost).

My tries was like defining the `crop` method and setting category there, but no luck...

products_controller.rb:

```
  def edit
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.category_id = params[:category_id]
    @product.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        if params[:product][:image].present?
          format.html { render :crop }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @product.category_id = params[:category_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        if params[:product][:image].present?
          format.html { render :crop }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }

          @products = Product.all
          ActionCable.server.broadcast 'products',
            html: render_to_string('store/index', layout: false)
        end
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

crop.html.erb (in products folder):

```
<%= image_tag @product.image_url(:large), id: "cropbox" %>

<h4>Preview</h4>
<div style="width:300px; height:200px; overflow:hidden;">
  <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:large), :id => "preview" %>
</div>

<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Crop" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I haven't tried to set a callback that stores category_id, but I wonder would it be a good idea? Any help? Thanks!

EDIT - also adding a form partial, but it works fine - just for your curiosity:

```
<%= form_for(product, hmtl: { multipart: true } ) do |f| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, @product.category_id), include_blank: "Select Category") %>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Logs for these actions:

```
Started GET "/products/new" for ::1 at 2016-12-15 09:03:31 +0200
Processing by ProductsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mCart Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering products/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mCategory Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"[0m
  Rendered products/_form.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"[0m
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = $1[0m  [["cart_id", 5]]
Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 113.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)


Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2016-12-15 09:03:40 +0200
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eWZuqL6AqcN8wknjEL115ax9uBnpY4b9eP0o2xN2aPntd61YKyc4Ym1lUgjV1YrXfZbPr57HANXy7Kz5swCtlg==", "product"=>{"title"=>"kj", "description"=>"kj", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe40ba4abe0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dn/zq9x2jkd4856kwhfj5gbz2tc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20161215-3987-1adfacs.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2016-12-05 at 09.14.48.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2016-12-05 at 09.14.48.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "price"=>"98", "quantity"=>"98"}, "category_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create Product"}
  [1m[36mCart Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mCategory Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "products" ("title", "description", "price", "quantity", "created_at", "updated_at", "category_id", "user_id", "image") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["title", "kj"], ["description", "kj"], ["price", #<BigDecimal:7fe40ccf9110,'0.98E2',9(18)>], ["quantity", 98], ["created_at", 2016-12-15 07:03:41 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-15 07:03:41 UTC], ["category_id", "1"], ["user_id", 1], ["image", "Screen_Shot_2016-12-05_at_09.14.48.png"]]
  [1m[35m (3.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  Rendering products/crop.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/crop.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
  [1m[36mCategory Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"[0m
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = $1[0m  [["cart_id", 5]]
Completed 200 OK in 957ms (Views: 127.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
```

So I noticed that it renders `products/crop.html.erb` without a particular ID, so I added in my routes:

```
  resources :products do
    get 'crop', on: :member
  end
```

And products_controller create action:

```
...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        if params[:product][:image].present?
          format.html { render crop_product_path(@product) }
        else
...
```

Still the same error, that a category must be selected. 
And to note - if simply go to edit product (but not from the `crop` action), category sits there as supposed...

Comment: Try adding `hidden_field` for `category_id` in your `crop.html` view. and set it to `@product.category_id`. Then you can later retrieve the value in `update` action

Comment: Hm, nice catch, but then I get `undefined method {:category_id=>"1"}'`... Tried to define product in crop action in products controller... Hidden field:    `<%= f.hidden_field :category_id => @product.category_id %>`

Comment: if you put the hidden field inside form, it will go under `product` so to get category_id in update action it will be under `params[:product][:category_id]`

Comment: and take a look at how to set hidden field in http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Comment: That works! Many thanks. Could you post as answer? So I could accept it

Comment: done :) Glad I could help

Comment: Glad to receive it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since form only submits the parameters gathered which are defined in it, you should add a hidden field to set the `category_id` in `crop.html` view

```
<%= image_tag @product.image_url(:large), id: "cropbox" %>

<h4>Preview</h4>
<div style="width:300px; height:200px; overflow:hidden;">
  <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:large), :id => "preview" %>
</div>

<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Crop" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, when you submit the form, you will receive `category_id` on server in `params[:product][:category_id]`